# Cannot Able To Start Named services in ssh

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, httpd, named-conf

My web application **domain.com:9080/webapp**  was working fine. Bu i would like to remove port number from address. One of forum person suggested me http://www.virtualmin.com/node/19608 link and i changed httpd.conf file. after that my webapplication is not working i changed httpd.conf again back to normal, but got errors.
Problem ..

**1. Service Named is not starting.**

```
[root@ipaddress/]# service named start
Starting named:
Error in named configuration:
zone domain.com/IN: loading from master file domain.com failed: file not found
zone domain.com/IN: not loaded due to errors.
_default/domain.com/IN: file not found
zone 50.121.188.in-addr.arpa/IN: loading from master file 50.121.188.in-addr.arpa failed: file not found
zone 50.121.188.in-addr.arpa/IN: not loaded due to errors.
_default/50.121.188.in-addr.arpa/IN: file not found
                                                           [FAILED]
[root@ipaddress/]#
```

**2. Service Httpd Not Working ..**

```
 service httpd start
Starting httpd: (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
                                                           [FAILED]
```

Comment: Why do you need `named` anyway? Your DNS shouldn't be running on the webserver, especially if you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: I think your apache process is still runing. It looks as if it didn't shut down properly before. The sentence "Address alread in use" is my indicator for that. And your named isn't configured as it seems.

Comment: Error: Unable to make action: Unable to manage service by dnsmng: dnsmng: Service /etc/init.d/named failed to start ('--start', 'dns')

Answer (score 0):

These are two separate errors.

The named one seems to be that the file for the zone is not found. You'll need to check your named configuration and then ensure the files are there (note that in a lot of circumstances named runs in a chroot environment so when it refers to /var/named/zones/X.zone the actual filepath is /var/named/chroot/var/named/zones/X.zone).

With apache, as the other poster mentioned, it looks like it's still running so cannot bind to the address (either that or perhaps something else is still running).

Stop apache and then check to ensure no httpd processes are running still, kill them if they are. After than apache should start.